# PHPSpreadSheet 20000 registros

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Hace poco que trabajo con la librería **`PHPSpreadSheet`** para leer y crear archivos de Excel con un navegador. EL problema es el siguiente:

He tratado de crear un Excel con base a registros de una tabla en SQL, el resultado de la consulta es aproximadamente de 20,000 registros. Por lo que me arroja un error de memoria, he intentado cargar los registros de 5,000 en 5,000 pero no funciona.

Me muestra el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12582920 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\vPemex\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Collection\Cells.php on line 144

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar al principio de tu archivo php lo siguiente:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

No es una solución muy recomendada, pero permitirá usar más memoria del servidor de forma temporal. [Límite de recursos PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

Comment: Fabian, gracias pero busco algo mas allá, establecer ese limite de memoria podría afectarme en los demás usuarios y servicios del servidor.

Comment: @AlejandroFlores PHPSpreadSheet no es muy bueno con el uso de la memoria, en especial con archivos muy grandes, te dejo dos links de la documentación que puedes investigar: 1) [Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate yyy bytes) in zzz on line aaa](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/faq/#fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-xxx-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-yyy-bytes-in-zzz-on-line-aaa) in zzz on line aaa) y 2) [Memory saving](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/memory_saving/)

Comment: Muchas gracias Fabian no se como pero he podido realizar la descarga del archivo con Cache-Control: age-max:0 en el Header! :S, Ahora tengo otro problema al leer el archivo con los formatos del excel-

Answer (score 0):

Debes optimizar tu código al máximo.

- Reduce las peticiones SQL.
- Usar las funciones propias de PHP.
- Elimina los dato no necesarios.
- Evita los cuellos de botella.
- Evita la copia de variables.
- ETC,ETC,ETC

En resumen,  **revisa el numero de bucles anidados que tienes. Ademas, no implementes mas estructuras de control de las necesarias**.

Para evaluar y comparar la eficiencia de varios fragmentos de código, la mejor (y casi única) opción es utilizar un Benchmark. Echa un vistazo a esta https://phpbench.com/

Otra opción es aumentar el limite de memoria para dicho script.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

Comment: esto es mas una opinión genérica de lo que debería hacer y no una respuesta clara y concreta, por que no indicas el como; lee [answer]

Comment: En la pregunta no hay lineas de código, para ayudar a su optimización.

Comment: si, sin embargo las respuestas en SO deben ser claras, aplicables de manera sistematizada, por que de todo eso que le mencionas no indicas en ningún momento como hacerlo

Comment: Ya he añadido mas información a mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las recomendaciones es ampliar la memoria como ya varios lo mencionan

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

Ademas de la optimización de consultas SQL y código en general hay que revisar algunas recomendaciones para el uso de la biblioteca.

**Memoria**

Establecer almacenamiento en cache. Esto le permite reducir el uso de memoria para libros de trabajo grandes:

```
$cache = new MyCustomPsr16Implementation();
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings::setCache($cache);
```

[Memory saving](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/memory_saving)

**Estilos**

Si agregas estilos usa el método `applyFromArray()` que es más eficiente que formatear cada celda.

[Formatting cells](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells)

**Hoja activa**

Establecer la hoja activa una vez:

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1','Celda 1');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1','Celda 1');
```

Con `$sheet` accedes al método `getActiveSheet()` una vez.

También puedes aprovechar la interfaz fluida para varias celdas en un llamado:

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1','Celda 1')->setCellValue('B1','Celda 2');
```

**Valores de celda**

En lugar de establecer el valor para cada celda individualmente, use el método `fromArray()`.

```
$arrayData = [
    [NULL, 2010, 2011, 2012],
    ['Q1',   12,   15,   21],
    ['Q2',   56,   73,   86],
    ['Q3',   52,   61,   69],
    ['Q4',   30,   32,    0],
];

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->fromArray(
        $arrayData,
        NULL,
        'C3' // Coordenada superior izquierda del rango de la hoja de trabajo
             //donde queremos establecer estos valores (el predeterminado es A1)
    );
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estas son algunas configuraciones que me han servidor para mejorar el procesamiento y generación de archivos Excel con miles de registros.**